# NSString Decoding - Changing Images To Text

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, nsstring

I working off some open source code, which currently is converting DTMF tones and then displaying them as images in `UIImageview`.
However, we really need a way to change this, so instead the content of each ImageView, is replaced by `UILabel` instead with the generated output being a string rather than an image.
I hope this makes sense:

Here is the original code responsible for this task:

```
- (void)setLCDString:(char*)content {

if (strlen(content) > LCD_COLS) {

    content = content + (strlen(content)-LCD_COLS);
}
//NSLog(@"LCDString %d len",strlen(content));

UIImageView *disp[LCD_COLS] = {a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o};

for (int in = 0; in < LCD_COLS; in++) {

//Here we start at 0, and if our INT is less than 24 (6x4) then we increase INT by 1.

    [disp[in] setImage:[self charToImage:*content]];

//Here we set UIImageVIew to our INT, and convert Character to images.

    if (*content) content++;
  }
}


- (UIImage *)charToImage:(char) chr
{

if (isdigit(chr) || (chr == 'A') || (chr == 'B') || (chr == 'C') || (chr == 'D')
        || (chr == '*') || (chr == '#')) {

    char name[10];

    snprintf(name,10,"%c.png",chr);;

    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithCString:name encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];

    return img;
}

return nil;
}
```

Here you can see, that the decoding is converting the string to an image in an individual `UIImageView`, but we need this replaced by `UILabel` with text.

If anyone can point us in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So what is the problem? You already look up the image by name! Just pass back that string and put it in a `UILabel` of your choosing.

Comment: Hi Johan,Thank you for getting back to me. Unfortunately Im not entirely sure how to do that :( Im fairly new to coding. Any chance you could provide a pointer if you have time?